# How to avoid strange structure artifacts in scaled images?

Tags: qt, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

I create a big image stitched out of many single microscope images.
Suddenly, (after several month of working properly) the stitched overview images became blurry and they are containing strange structural artefacts like askew lines (not the rectangulars, they are because of not perfect stitching)

[image: Stitched image with strange structural artefacts]

If I open any particular tile in full size, they are not blurry and the artefacts are hardly observable. (Consider, the image below is already 4x scaled)

[image: Single tile image without artefacts]

The overview image is created manually by scaling each tile using QImage::scaled and copying all of them to the corresponding region in the big image. I'm not using opencv's stitching.

I assume, this happens because of image contents, because most if the overview images are ok.

The question is, how can I avoid such hardly observable artefacts to become very clearly visible after scaling? Is there some means in OpenCV or QImage?
Is there any algorithms to find out, if image content could lead to such effect for defined scale-factor?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: in your full size image you can see the artifacts too!!

Comment: @Micka: True, but actually the image is already scaled. On the original image 5MP it is hardly observable. I had problems persuading the customer, that the artifacts are in the original image already there. But, the magic is, the more you scale it, the better these artifacts are visible and the more they dominate the entire image. On the other images done with the same camera but having different structure of object, this effect is hardly observable. So it seems to depend on the image content/texture.

Comment: When you called scaled, did you try passing `Qt::SmoothTransformation` as the transformation type parameter? It generally gives best results than the default (which is `Qt::FastTransformation`).

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for image resizing ?

Comment: can you please post/link a single 5MP image??

Comment: can you create a constant white material to create some "reference image" that should be completely white in your image? You might want to avoid/overcome different effects too, like vignetting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you **sure** the camera is calibrated properly? That the lightning is uniform? Is the lens clear? Do you have electrical components that interfere with the camera connection?

If you add image frames of photos on a uniform material (or non-uniform material, moved randomly for significant time), the resultant integrated image should be completely uniform.

If your produced image is not uniform, especially if you get systematic noise (like the apparent sinusoidal noise in the provided pictures), write a calibration function that transforms image -> calibrated image.

Filtering in Fourier space is another way to filter out the noise but considering that the image is rotated you will lose precision, and you'll be cutting off components of the real signal, too. The following empiric method will reduce the noise in your particular case significantly:

1. ground_output: composite image with per-pixel sum of >10 frames (more is better) over uniform material (e.g. excited slab of phosphorus)
2. ground_input: the average(or sqrt(sum of px^2)) in ground_output
3. calib_image: ground_input /(per px) ground_output. Saved for the session, or persistent in a file (important: ensure no lossy compression! (jpeg)).
4. work_input: the images to work on
5. work_output = work_input *(per px) calib_image: images calibrated for systematic noise.

If you can't create a perfect ground_input target such as having a uniform material on hand, do not worry too much. If you move any material uniformly (or randomly) for enough time, it will act as a uniform material in this case (think of a blurred photo).

This method has the added advantage of calibrating solitary faulty pixels that ccd cameras have (eg NormalPixel.value(signal)).

If you want to have more fun you can always fit the calibration function to something more complex than a zero-intercept line (steps 3. and 5.).

Comment: Thank you very much. Checking electrical components is a good point, which we have not considered until now. However the process of calibration is not easy in my case as the resolution of the optics is less than 1 um/dot. It is not easy to find uniform material for this density. Actually, my question was how to avoid such artefacts to become so visible on scaling. On a full-screen image they are hardly observable.

Comment: I would also suggest some king of filter that is filtering the "sinusoidal noise", it seems that it is the same for all slices. Is it the same for other images?

Comment: @sop Not in all. Most of the images are fine. First I thought, it depends on the content of the image (e.g. not that observable on images with more contrast or details) but the power-line noise is more likely to be the cause - e.g. the fridge or a centrifuge starts starts to work in the lab. Can you suggest such a filter which is ideally implemented in OpenCV?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz do you have phosphorus handy and a way to excite it on the spot?

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov: Thanks for new info in edit! The optics guy used to try some substances but we skipped it. What he tried was, simulating the fluorescence. It didn't work, as was too different from biologic material. However, for such kind of calibration it should work. Especially for finding black spots. Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest scaling the image with some other software to verify if the artifacts are in fact caused by Qt or are inherent in the image you've captured.

The askew lines look a lot like analog tv interference, or [CCTV](http://camsat-cctv.com/s/support/technical-support/help-for-cctv-installers) noise induced by 50 or 60 Hz power lines running alongside the signal cable or some other electrical interference on the signal.

If the image distortion is caused by signal interference then you can try to mitigate it by moving the signal lines away from whatever could be the source of the problem, or fit something to try to filter the noise (baluns for example).

Comment: It is an interesting observation concerning the lines. Indeed, most images from the same machine don't show this. The machines are in a lab with many other devices and fridges. Maybe some device causes this power-line noise. I can't avoid it. The only possibility is to handle it in software. The artifacts are definitely inherent in the image. The bigger image is scaled down 4x with  Windows' mspaint. It also shows the artifacts.

Comment: Start by creating the FFT of the slice, and see if you find the 50hz noise; otherwise you can add aluminium around the cable from the camera to the computer. If it is not a direct connection, then it is getting more complicated, so focus on filtering the image